# How do I make HTML5 widgets with interactive features?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed, slideshow

I am a beginner (4 months of experience with HTML5) volunteering at a non-profit and I want to create an embeddable widget.  I want to make it interactive, like I want to display a few pictures that work the way a flash ad will (think slideshow effect) and I want to be able to make it shareable to social networks and if someone wants they can embed the widget they can.  In addition, I want to be able to put buttons that take them to other pages.

I have been searching it on the web and it seems iframes are the way to go.  Am I correct or is there another way to achieve what I want to?

UPDATE:

I need something like what's shown here as an example: http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_iframe_tag.cfm

but with options of sharing it and call-to-action options with slideshow.

Comment: did you create the widget already?

Comment: @ibu not yet.  i just have have the images and all but i need to be able to put them in a slideshow kind of a thing.  So not sure how to begin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iframe` tag is useful for 'embedding' your widget on someone else's page (it's the way Youtube videos get embedded). Bear in mind that everywhere that the traffic generated by the content of that `iframe` will count against your bandwidth, regardless of where it's placed, since it acts like a 'portal' to that content on your server.

Comment: So I am right in wanting to use iframes? Any idea how I can squeeze in a slideshow with the features I need? Thanks.

Comment: I need something like what's shown here as an example: http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_iframe_tag.cfm

but with options of sharing it and call-to-action options with slideshow.

Comment: Just build a webpage with the functionality you want and then link it into an iframe. It should work!

Comment: @funkymonk91 OK.  So i guess it's as easy as that.  lol.  thanks.

Comment: More or less. As Justin said: "it acts like a 'portal' to that content on your server."

I would make it with a size restraint in mind. Think about how big you want your iframe widget to be on someone else's page. Code for those size restraints.

Comment: @KPO Most of the modern ones should support it. Support is going to differ from browser to browser.